# How to copy the entered text in dialog with button from code?

Tags: dialog, copy-paste, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to copy the text in **DialogBox** in my `clipboard` from code after button click.

I need in my dialog a button with function ctrl+c .

I have this code for my **Dialog**:

```
Dialog      dialog;
DialogField dialogField;
str string;
;
dialog = new Dialog("My personal dialog");
dialogField= dialog.addFieldvalue(extendedTypeStr(String30), string, "insert the text to be copied");

// ctrl + c button
//I need a button  with the function to copy the text entered
dialog.run();
if (dialog.closedOk())
{
}
}
```

Thanks for help,

enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [TextBuffer.fromClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/textbuffer.fromclipboard.aspx) method.

Example use:

```
TextBuffer txtb = new textBuffer(); 
#define.ExampleFile(@"c:\test.txt") 
#define.ExampleOpenMode("w") 

// Set code access permission to help protect the use of TextBuffer.tofile 
new FileIoPermission(#ExampleFile, #ExampleOpenMode).assert(); 

if ( txtb.fromClipboard() ) 
{ 
    // Got text from clipboard - save it to file 
    txtb.toFile(#ExampleFile); 
} 

// Close the code access permission scope. 
CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
```

It should be easy to adapt to a dialog.

Comment: Thanks @JanB.Kjeldsen I appreciate your help.
I had seen that way, but my problem is to use the copied text. I want to paste the copied text when the **Dialog** is closed. It's possible?

Comment: Use `toClipboard` instead

Comment: I used, but don't work, I have to write the code differently?

Comment: Hi @JanB.Kjeldsen !
Thanks for help.
I have this code:
`static void Job(Args _args)
{
    TextBuffer txtb = new textBuffer(); 
    #define.ExampleFile(@"c:\test.txt") 
    #define.ExampleOpenMode("text to copy") 

    new FileIoPermission(#ExampleFile, #ExampleOpenMode).assert(); 

    if ( txtb.fromClipboard() ) 
    { 
    //txtb.toFile(#ExampleFile); 
        txtb.toClipboard();
    } 

    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
}`
After I launched the **Job** I can't paste with  _ctrl+c_ the text.

Comment: I want to have by code the functionality **Ctrl+C** Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen for your help.