# Copy text to Clipboard in AX365

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I added a button that will copy the following Text "This is a test" on your clipboard when the user Click on it. Any idea how to do that in x++ for D365 ?

Comment: I removed the `dynamic` and `dynamic-programming` tags, these are not related to Microsoft Dynamics. I replaced them with some Microsoft Dynamics 365 tags instead. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846504/how-to-copy-the-entered-text-in-dialog-with-button-from-code) shows an AX2012 to get something _from_ the clipboard, adding something _to_ it should be similar. But the `TextBuffer` API has been [deprecated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/migration-upgrade/deprecated-apis). Microsoft suggests the .NET `StreamReader` class. Give it a try!

Comment: @Sander StreamReader is for file reading vs I am just displaying a static text here? any advice on how to use StreamReader that way ?

Comment: My apologies, there are only 2 methods deprecated on `TextBuffer` (both methods concern file interaction, so Microsoft's suggestion makes sense now). This means that the `TextBuffer` class from the AX2012 example I linked earlier could still be an option or you can try something with [`System.Windows.Forms.ClipBoard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-add-data-to-the-clipboard).

Comment: @Sander the issue with using windows form, that it wont work with browser application as this is for dynamics 365.

Comment: I played around a bit with this, but found no way to get it to work. `TextBuffer.toClipboard` runs, but does not seem to actually put something to the clipboard. `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData` and `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetData` do compile, but throw a ThreadStateException at runtime.

Comment: @FH-Inway I get the same thing where the textbuffer doesnt do anything and the windows clipboard throw an exception.